# C# POST data to a PHP file and get answer

Tags: c#, windows, post

I'm creating a Windows universal app using Visual Studio 2017 RC Community version and I want to send data from the app to a PHP file and get the answer.
I know how to do it in classic apps using Windows Form, but I cant find out how it would work here !

Here is my code after searching and trying to understand :

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ButtonSubmit_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string email = TextEmail.Text;

    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

    string PostData = "email=" + email;

    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(PostData);

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("URL TO PHP File");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Headers["ContentLength"] = data.Length.ToString();

    Stream stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

    stream = response.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader ar = new StreamReader(stream);

    BlockInfo.Text = ar.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Now I don't have any error in my code but the problem is that I would like to run the code when clicking on the `ButtonSubmit`, but I don't know how to make it work.

**Update**

I found how to resolve the problem, but I have an error now The `ButtonSubmit_ClickAsync` has the wrong return type

Now I don't know how to resolve this problem !

Comment: have you tracked your button event? put a breakpoint and see where is the problem.

Comment: @Valkyriee Thank you, I found that, I needed to change my button click value !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Okay I found the answer and my problem totally resolved :)**

*I changed this part :*

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ButtonSubmit_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

*To :*

```
private async void ButtonSubmit_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

And it's working perfectly :)